# private member functions & structs and helpers local to the implementation file

Tags: c++

Consider a class with a set of methods

```
class myClass {
  private:
    int someFunc(const SomeClass&);
  public:
    funcA();
    funcB();
    funcC();
}
```

Inside the implementation file, I have a local struct definition and some helper functions using this in an anonymous namespace

```
namespace {
  struct Foo { ... };
  int helperFunc(const Foo&){
    SomeClass c;
    // do stuff with Foo and SomeClass to calculate someInteger
    return someInteger;
  }
  Foo makeFoo(){
     Foo foo;
     // configure foo
     return foo;
  }
}

myClass::funcA(){
  Foo foo = makeFoo();
  return helperFunc(foo);
}
myClass::funcB(){
  Foo foo = makeFoo();
  return helperFunc(foo);
}
myClass::funcC(){
  Foo foo = makeFoo();
  return helperFunc(foo)
}
```

Now, I discovered that I need to change the `helperFunc` to use `someFunc(c)`, a private method of `myClass`.

Ideally, I would like to

- keep the defintion of `Foo` local to the anonymous namespace
- keep `someFunc` private
- keep `helperFunc` as a function, because it's used multiple times in the class implementation
- keep `makeFoo` separate from `helperFunc`, because it's used separately in some cases

As a last resort, one could convert `helperFunc` to a precompiler macro, but I consider this not very elegant and still hope that there is some trick that I'm unaware of to achieve my goals.

I greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: `helperFunc` requires to use `someFunc` or only the value returned from it? Maybe you can call in in `funcA`, `funcB`, `funcC`?

Comment: `helperFunc` requires only the value returned by `someFunc`, but `someFunc` takes as an argument things that instantiated locally inside `helperFunc`. Thanks for raising this point, I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Why not to declare Foo or Foo::helperFunc as a friend of class myClass? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Comment: In my understanding, the `friend` declaration would need to happen inside the definition of `myClass`. That would in turn require to declare the argument type `Foo` in the header of `myClass`, which I don't want to do.

Comment: `#define private public` ;-)

Comment: @carsten, you can use just forward declaration for struct Foo in class myClass: friend struct detail::Foo. You would then need to give the namespace a name (e.g. "detail") instead of having unnamed namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more than a single way to do it. Personally, I'd go with:

```
namespace detail
{
    int myClassSomeFuncAccessor(const SomeClass&);
}

class myClass {
  private:
    int someFunc(const SomeClass&);
  public:
    int funcA();
    int funcB();
    int funcC();

  private:
    friend int detail::myClassSomeFuncAccessor(const SomeClass&);
};
```

It has pros and cons.

Pros:

- Decouples the class and its accessor from the implementation classes
- `detail` namespace accessor signifies that this is not part of the "official public" interface

Cons:

- The decoupling is indeed decoupled: anyone can access the internals through the `detail` namespace accessor

Comment: It someone's accesses internals through `details` they are basically asking for trouble, one step further and they would do `#define private public`

Comment: @kwesoly I agree with you that it's a con. Notwithstanding, this approach is very well established. The gtest docs advocate it. Python embraces it.

Comment: I was rather pointing out that it is not a real Con. It is dangerous only to small user subset which are dangerous to themselves :)

Answer (score 4):

You could pass an `std::function` object to `helperFunc`. This object can be constructed from your private method using `std::bind`:

```
namespace {
  ...
  int helperFunc(const Foo&, std::function<int(const SomeClass&)> func){
    SomeClass c;
    ...
    // Invoke passed-in function
    int funcResult = func(c);
    ...
    return someInteger;
  }
  ...
}

myClass::funcA(){
  Foo foo = makeFoo();
  return helperFunc(foo, std::bind(&myClass::someFunc, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think now is the perfect occasion of use of C++ keyword 'friend'. Simply make your inner class friend of the encapsulator. This is the cleanest and language supported solution.
In an [article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html) about the topic by Alex Allain he explains it nicely how friend in C++ are not taboo by saying

> Some people believe that the idea of having friend classes violates the principle of encapsulation because it means that one class can get at the internals of another. One way to think about this, however, is that friend is simply part of a class's overall interface that it shows the world. Just like an elevator repairman has access to a different interface than an elevator rider, some classes or functions require expanded access to the internals of another class. Moreover, using friend allows a class to present a more restrictive interface to the outside world by hiding more details than may be needed by anything but the friends of the class.

Comment: Good point, but note that you can't declare a function in an anonymous namespace as a friend. So to go this route, you'd need to take the approach of Ami Tavory.